# C# Sort number by sequence partition

Tags: c#

I am having the data as follow :

5
2
2
1
3
3
4

I want output in C# as follow :

1
2
3
4
5
2
3

So basically all the unique values sorted first in ASC order than again start with remaining items...

Comment: Thank you for sharing this with us. Have a nice day.

Comment: Quite difficult I'll say :-)

Comment: Now I'm really interested if there already is an optimized algorithm for this problem...

Comment: Is the answer Quick Sort? Is it?

Comment: "all the unique values sorted first" I see only two unique numers 1 and 4. So why your expected otuput is not `1 4 5 2 2 3 3`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll say that it is quite complex... But it piqued my interest... Note that this solution is very simple. If you want multi-field ordering or reverse ordering and so on it becomes more complex:

```
public static class OrderByTest
{
    private static int Increment<TKey>(Dictionary<TKey, int> dict, TKey key)
    {
        int value;

        if (dict.TryGetValue(key, out value))
        {
            value++;
        }

        dict[key] = value;
        return value;
    }

    public static IEnumerable<TSource> OrderByPartition<TSource, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector)
    {
        var dict = new Dictionary<TKey, int>();

        var res = source.Select(x => new { Value = x, Partition = Increment(dict, keySelector(x)) }).OrderBy(x => x.Partition).ThenBy(x => keySelector(x.Value));

        foreach (var value in res)
        {
            yield return value.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

then use it like:

```
var values = new[] { 5, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 4 };
var ordered = values.OrderByPartition(x => x).ToArray();
```

It is a Linq-style solution, so it produces a new ordered sequence, not an in-place solution like `Array.Sort`. The basic idea is to add the partition number to your collection. To have the partition number, we use a temporary `Dictionary<TKey, int>` containing the number of elements with the same `TKey` that have already been found.

Comment: Indeed quite elegant. Interesting how easy one can do stuff with LINQ and make it readable as well.

Answer (score 1):

You could group the data by value, sort the groups, then iterate the groups keeping the counts in mind - either decrement each time and remove things when they reach zero, or increment a counter and only output things that are at least that populous. Something like:

```
var values = new[] { 5, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 4 };
var data = new SortedDictionary<int, int>();
foreach(var val in values)
{
    int count;
    if (!data.TryGetValue(val, out count)) count = 0;
    data[val] = count + 1;
}

int lim = 0;
bool any;
do
{
    any = false;
    foreach (var pair in data)
        if (pair.Value > lim)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(pair.Key);
            any = true;
        }
    lim++;
} while (any);
```